# VPN can't access local IPs

Tags: vpn, l2tp

i have mac mini with OS X mavericks at the office. We have server app installed their and I connect succesfully but L2TP but can access only the mac mini and can't access other local computers.

This may be a problem with some NAT or ...?

**Office:**

- Network: 192.168.0.1 to 100  - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ribs9ej01fg82i/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-28%20at%209.47.01%20PM.png
- Port forwarding: to 192.168.0.2 mac mini
- No firewall or something else
- Virtual machine on 192.168.0.10 it's accessible from the office
- the vpn ip address that server give me is 192.168.0.101 to 121

**Home**

- one modem
- one d-link router
- i connect to my office with L2TP VPN - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qa25few7xt7qnv3/Screen%20Shot%202013-11-28%20at%209.47.13%20PM.png

MY problem is that i can't access 192.168.0.10 or any other local ip address from our office.

Comment: Yeah sure there is a problem!!! Please add more details!

Comment: when you say 'other local computers' do you mean local to your office network, or local to the network your client is on. they are on different networks, right (establishing a VPN connection to the network you are already physically connected to usually doesn't work right)?

Comment: I update my problem. Yes i connect to my office but can't access one computer in the office

Comment: so you cannot ping 192.168.0.10 from 192.168.0.2? you are using IP addresses not hostnames, right? I notice that you don't have the office DNS server specified in your connection so hostnames likely will not resolve unless you use an FQDN. Also I'm not clear on what you mean by port forwarding. your router should not need to forward ports directly to your mac. when you vpn, you are connecting to the network, not the host. your mac mini isn't set up as the VPN endpoint, right? you are connecting to the router, not the mac, right?

Comment: Airport has port forwarding to 192.168.0.2 - VPN ports. I can't pink from home 192.168.0.10 that is the computer in our office.

Comment: ok. I'm not a mac guy so mabey thats the issue. if you are vpning directly into the mac mini, then it makes perfect sense that you cannot contact other hosts. if you are vpning into the network that the mac is on, then you should be able to connect to any device on that network. it sounds like you are connecting directly to the mac though. since this is p2p, see if you can enable split-tunneling on the server end (your mac mini).

Comment: Could you please post your routing table? Thank you

Comment: Here is the table and my network settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/xknbfwiyw9pw5ih/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-01%20at%2012.49.33%20PM.png

Comment: I find a solution it was so simple. If your network in the office is 192.168.0.1 at home can't be the same. It should be 192.168.1.1